# MMSE (Minimum min square estimate) problem

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, mean-square-error

I have a problem as follows. As of now, I cannot provide the definition of X and Y but can anyone provide a rough overview of what needs to be done ?

> An experiment
> consist of rolling a single die and the experimental outcome
> determines a value for X and Y. (the random variables X and Y are defined Table)
>
> a) Find a constant a that will give a
> mininmum mean-square estimate of X and calculate the resulting
> mean-square error.
>
> b) Given that Y=4, find the minimum mean-square
> estimate of X and the resulting mean-square error

Comment: Please provide more context about how the die roll is related to X and Y. It is not clear if X and Y are completely determined by the die roll, or only probabilistically so. The actual table of values would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean of a distribution is the estimate that minimizes the mean square error.

For example, imagine that we are going to draw $x$, and it can be $0$ or $1$ with equal (50%) probability.  We make an estimate $\hat{x}$ to minimize the mean square error:

$$
\min_\hat{x} \  E\left[(x-\hat{x})^2\right]
$$

where the $E$ means expected value.

Using calculus, the mean square error is minimized by a choice of $\hat{x}$ that satisfies:

$$
0 = E\left[-2\left(x-\hat{x}\right)\right]
$$

Dividing both sides by $-2$ and rearranging, we get

$$
\hat{x} = E\left[x\right]
$$

So we should guess $\hat{x} = 0.5$ in this case.

For your problem, in part a), the answer will be the expected value of $X$, and in part b), the answer will be the expected value of $X$ conditional on $Y=4$.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Also, do you know how I can get the residual error ?

Comment: It really is not necessary to use "calculus" to derive the result $\hat{x} = E[x]$ minimizes the mean square error. Using $\mu$ to denote $E[x]$, we have $$\begin{align}E[(x-\hat{x})^2] &= E[(x-\mu +\mu-\hat{x})^2]\\&= E[(x-\mu)^2] + E[(\mu-\hat{x})^2] + 2E[(x-\mu)(\mu-\hat{x})]\\&= E[(x-\mu)^2] + (\mu-\hat{x})^2 \end{align}$$ since the last term on the right is $0$ and the middle term is a nonnegative constant. Thus, the minimum value of $E[(x-\hat{x})^2]$ occurs when the constant on the right is $0$, that is, when $\hat{x} = \mu = E[x]$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thanks! Any ideas for residual error ?

Comment: The residual error is the mean square error left over when we use the best estimator, $\hat{x}$.  It's therefore $E[(x-\hat{x})^2]$, which is the variance of $x$. Try calculating that based on the values you have.

Comment: @TomP Great thanks for your help !